# using Dependency resolver with autofac wcf integration

Tags: c#, wcf, autofac

I am working on a wcf project and using autofac for it and it's working.
However, my requirement is that I will be deploying this service on different systems and it needs to use the assemblies present on those systems.
For e.g. my wcf uses Assembly1 & Assembly2 and I can reference these assemblies in the project on my pc and build the service and it runs fine.

However, these Assemblies will be of different version on different systems where wcf will be deployed. So I can't just ship my Assemblies with the wcf service. I have configured below AssemblyResolver in one of the class' constructor that I am registering first in autofac, and trying to load the Assembly1 & Assembly2 from a different path where I have copied these assemblies and trying to load it via Assembly.LoadFrom.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveAssembly;
```

But when I am deleting the Assembly1 & Assembly2 from my wcf bin folder in PostBuildEvent and thinking that ResolveAssembly should look for those assemblies in the provided folder. But it is not trying to load assembly using the ResolveAssembly event handler. Wcf service fails on below line saying that it can't find Assembly1 or Assembly2.

```
AutofacHostFactory.Container = container;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem you have is that `.NET` may load the assembly before the `AssemblyResolve` event has a chance to handle the absence of those assemblies. This can happen if your code for installing `AssemblyResolve` already references examples from these assemblies.

You'll want to make sure you're subscribing to the `AssemblyResolve` event as soon as your application kicks off, before it tries to look for any of those external assemblies. This means setting it up at the start of your `Main` method or the application's entry point.

It can look like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(ResolveAssembly);

    // Other startup code can go here
}
```

Make sure you're not throwing any surprises for your application by using the exact version of assemblies it expects. If the versions are going to be different in each deployment, you might not want to reference specific versions in your project.

A few other tips:

1. Keep an eye on `Fusion Log Viewer (fuslogvw.exe)` to check if the assembly binding is tripping up. [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer)
2. Make sure your `Autofac` container knows the score and is set up after your dynamic assembly loading is ready to rock.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you rewrite the ResolveAssembly method.

```
public static Assembly ResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            
            string assemblyPath = Path.Combine(DynamoPathManager.Instance.MainExecPath, new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll");
            if (File.Exists(assemblyPath))
            {
                return Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
            }

            
            foreach (var addPath in DynamoPathManager.Instance.AdditionalResolutionPaths)
            {
                assemblyPath = Path.Combine(addPath, new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll");
                if (File.Exists(assemblyPath))
                {
                    return Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} could not be resolved for loading.", args.Name), ex);
        }
    }
```